# TYPO3 pw_comments label doesn't count comments

Tags: typo3

I am currently working with TYPO3 extensions news + pw_comments. Works good so far but the `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pwCommentsGetCountWithLabel" />` always shows `0 Comments` instead of e.g. `1 Comment` if there is a comment of for a news.

The pw_comments config looks like this

```
plugin.tx_pwcomments {
    settings {
        storagePid = 111
        useEntryUid = 1
        entryUid = TEXT
        entryUidData = GP:tx_news_pi1 | news

        moderateNewComments = 0
        secondsBetweenTwoComments = 60

        sendMailOnNewCommentsTo = asfga@hotmail.de
        sendMailTemplate = fileadmin/private/ext/pw_comments/Templates/MailNotification/mail.html
    }
}
```

Is thereI have something wrong entryUid or something that I forgot? I am a little bit confused about the `useEntryUid = 1` because I don't know what to write here. Looked in the official documentation but I got my problems with that...

Can somebody hint me to the right way?

Snippet instead of cObject:

```
lib.test = CONTENT
lib.test {
table = tx_pwcomments_domain_model_comment
select {
    selectFields = count(*)
    pidInList = 111
    andWhere = entry_uid = {field:uid}
    andWhere.stdWrap.insertData = 1
}

renderObj = COA_INT
renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        wrap = Anzahl Kommentare:&nbsp; | 
        data = field:count(*)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: as far as I understand the manual (I don't use the extension) you need `useEntryUid = 1` if you want comments based on another value than the page uid. Here you use the uid of newsrecords.

Answer (score 0):

there is one line that looks suspicious:

```
entryUidData = GP:tx_news_pi1 | news
```

normaly I would expect:

```
entryUid.data = GP:tx_news_pi1 | news
```

Another reason for wrong values could be caching. Maybe you need to build an uncached TS-VH (make `lib.pwCommentsGetCountWithLabel` an `userInt`).

I think you need the config given in the old wiki (as that page is not included in the current manual): https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-pw_comments/wiki/Documentation#How-to-use-pw_comments-with-other-extensions

your config missed the TS-Condition so it is used only if there is a selection to only one tx-news record:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0 ]
  ## this config is only valid if one tx-news record is selected
  plugin.tx_pwcomments {
    settings {
        :
    }
  }
[global]
```

if you use a typoscript viewhelper (as you have added) be sure to provide the variable `{field:uid}` with a value:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.test">{uid:item.uid}</f:cObject>
```

Comment: I looked up in the documentation and you're right, actually it should be `entryUid.data`. But if I write it like this every comment will be on every news page and also in the database table there is no entryuid written for a new comment. The typoscript object browser shows me in the constant this field `[entryUidData]` but in the setup it's like yours. Changes only applied when override the constant fields for whatever reason.

Comment: you need a unique key to identify the base for a comment. An `uid` as it is not unique as you do not know which kind of record (page, tt_content, tx-news-record ?) either you restrict to only one kind of record, or you store comments for different records in different pages, or you include the record-type into the key. this all needs to be reflected in the configuration where the comment is identified and fetched from. I have no configuration for pwcomment, but there might be some examples.

Comment: the old manual (wiki) has a documentation which is missing in the current manual. (I enhanced my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Saw this documentation too but it won't affect anything if I modify my code with yours. I found another snippet and edited in my question above. The thing is now it shows me all comments and not the ones for a special news page..

Comment: Thanks for your great help but I can't get it working...so I just let it be instead of wasting more hours to solve a problem which seemingly only I have...